# Как запустить асинхронную задачу Task на n секунд?

Tags: c#, async-await

Доброго времени суток!

Мне требуется асинхронно запустить некоторую задачу `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, но проблема в том, что она никогда не завершается, и мое приложение навсегда зависает в режиме ожидания ее выполнения.

Говоря конкретно, я работал с классом `SslStream`. На клиентском приложении я запускаю асинхронную операцию аутентификации (`await`) [`stream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(null)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclientasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream_AuthenticateAsClientAsync_System_String_). Сервер тут же отклоняет ее (проблема с сертификацией), а запущенная асинхронная операция, как оказалось, может провисеть бесконечно долго. В итоге мое клиентское приложение не может продолжать работу.

**Вопрос:** Как мне асинхронно запустить задачу `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` так, чтобы она была отменена через, например, 10 секунд?

Да, я вижу [эту](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclientasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream_AuthenticateAsClientAsync_System_Net_Security_SslClientAuthenticationOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) сладкую перегрузку метода, но она не подходит в силу моей платформы (**.Net Framework 4.8**).

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше информации, пока ничего не понятно, откуда что и куда вы вызываете.

Comment: В вопросе достаточно информации.

Comment: Отмена тасков, это токены отмены (`CancellationToken`), а у них есть таймаут (`CancelAfter`).

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне применить токен отмены применительно к задаче `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, которую возвращает мне метод `stream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так

```cs
int timeout = 500; // 500 миллисекунд
using (var stream = new SslStream(...))
{
    Task t = stream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(null);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(timeout)) == t)
    {
        // ваш код в случае успеха
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Timeout in AuthenticateAsClientAsync");
}
```

То есть саму процедуру авторизации не прерываем, но диспозим `SslStream`, если произошел таймаут. Собственно `Dispose()` и прервёт всё что нужно.

P.S. Пора бы уже переехать как минимум на .NET Core 3.1